# Solving a system of ODE that arose in solving Burgers' equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Consider the Burgers' equation $$\partial_t u = \alpha u\partial_xu$$ Intend to solve this using Fourier Galerkin method. So When I convert this into $N$th Fourier partial sum, I get a system of ODE's as follows $$\partial_t u_m = \sum_{k=-N}^{k=N}iku_ku_{m-k}    $$

How do I solve this system of ODE numerically or analytically?, given we know the first $N$ Fourier coefficients of the initial condition $u(x,0)$.

Comment: From what I googled, it seemed to be a coupled ODE. Wonder any ready made solution available?

Comment: Usually, you do the linear part of the time evolution in frequency space and the non-linear part in state space. Cf. the examples in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29803342/error-in-rk4-algorithm-in-python and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29617089/implement-pseudo-spectral-method-with-rk4-in-python

Comment: @LutzL : I am trying to solve in Fourier-Galerkin method, where it is done like this. But the references I read do not tell how the ODE is solved, perhaps thats a well known thing in the field of numerical PDE or CFD, I am trying hard to get references.

Comment: Use any of the standard solvers. Since quadratic systems tend to be stiff, preferably use an implicit solver. Many are based on the fortran code lsoda (? or lsode?).

Answer (score 0):

Analytic solving of the PDE :
$$\partial_t u - \alpha u\partial_xu=0$$
Thanks to the method of characteristics :
$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{-\alpha u}=\frac{du}{0}$$
On the characteristic curves : 
  \begin{cases}
    u=c_1\\
    \alpha c_1 dt +dx=0\:\:\rightarrow\:\: \alpha u t +x=c_2\\
  \end{cases}
The general solution can be expressed on the form : 
$$\Phi\left(u\:,\: \alpha t u +x\right)=0$$
where $\Phi$ is any derivable function of two variables. This is equivalent of the implicit relationship :
$$u=F\left(\alpha \;t\; u +x\right)$$
where $F$ is any derivable function.

Nothing can be done further until the boundary conditions be defined, in order to find the convenient function $F$ and then $u(x,t)$ when it is possible to explicit $u$ from the implicit equation.

Comment: Hi JJacquelin : Thnaks for the answer. My question is (what I want to learn) the solution of the coupled ODE system I have mentioned, and not the Burger's equation itself. Why I am interested is that I can build a computational model which can compute numerically, for any given initial data $u(x,0)$.